# C++ void pointer to get struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I'm trying to learn void pointer. I want to get the passed struct contents using a void pointer.

Here is my struct:

Main.cpp

```
struct mynode
{
    int id;
    int amt;
};
struct mynode* myNode;

int main()
{   
    myclass mc;
    mc.initialize(myNode);
    getch();
}
```

myclass.cpp

```
void initialize(void* data)
{
    //how to get passed struct here ?
}
```

Comment: You'd need to cast the pointer back to the struct type. The question I have though is **why** do you want to do it this way?

Comment: Your example won't compile, and also is really C. You shouldn't be using void pointers in C++. What are you trying to achieve (besides "learning void pointer")

Comment: @UnholySheep how can I cast it back ? like (struct *)data ?

Comment: `(struct mynode*)data`

Comment: @djgandy it compiles in mine. Trying to create dynamic structure assignment, like users can pass any structure and it will allocate memory.

Comment: @Aswin: The pointer is passed by value, so even if you allocate memory the caller won't receive a pointer to it.  Consider something like `template<typename T> void initialize(T*& data)` -- note the reference-to-pointer.

Comment: @Aswin what you are trying to do sounds fishy. And in C++ you would'nt even think about such a thing, may in C yes.

Comment: @Aswin How do you plan to allocate memory for a struct, without knowing the actual type of it?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis The struct name and actual data it contains will differ dynamically during runtime. In that case how can I do it ?

Comment: @Aswin short answer : no. The `initialize` function just "sees" a void pointer. It has absolutely no idea what the _actual_ type of the variable/structure it is pointing to is.

Comment: @MichaelWalz you mean it is not possible to do so ?

Comment: I think you need to give a more concrete example of what you are trying to  achieve. Your example will need more than one struct that can be passed as input to `initialize` to make it clear what your objective is. As your example stands, it makes absolutely no sense to delegate allocation to another function, when you know what you need to allocate at the call site.

Comment: @Aswin That's a good question and it's an indication that what you're doing is not the best way to proceed. By taking a `void*` you are erasing information about what kind of pointer it was originally. Do you *want* to erase that information? If not, use a template instead.

Comment: @Aswin "how can I do it?". In c++ you should do it with inheritance and composition of objects

Comment: @Aswin Please [read this](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: IMO from the limited information, you are probably wanting something like a factory method that will create many object types that all share a common interface. Hard to say for sure as you have only described the method of implementation, not the problem.

Comment: @MichaelWalz what if user allocates memory to struct like struct temp* = (struct temp)malloc(sizeof(struct mynode) then passes it to initialize like initialize(temp). Can I get the struct contents ?

Comment: @Aswin no, as I explained before, the void pointer `data` in `initialize` is just, welll... a void pointer. There is no way to find out dynamically to what type the void pointer points.

Comment: @Aswin Yes you can by casting, but why not just change the function signature?

Comment: @djgandy how can I do that ? I'm kinda new to this void pointers.

Comment: Despite all the really good advice above I'd like to add that using the names mynode as the struct name and myNode as the pointer name is bound to lead to a nasty bug at some time. How you change it is up to you but I would make them noticeably different to save you a day of head scratching when you mix them up. I could add that Hungarian notation is an option but it's so out of fashion that I can't recommend it.

Answer (score 6):

well, you can cast the pointer back to the original structure:

```
auto myStruct = static_cast<mynode*>(data);
```

although, your code is terribly C-like in the use of `void*`.

In C++, you are encouraged to use static polymorphism in the form of templates:

```
template<class Dependency>
void initialize(Dependency& data){/*...*/}
```

or dynamic polymorphism, in the form of inheritance and overriding:

```
struct BaseNode{
  virtual ~BaseNode() = default;
};

struct MyNode : public BaseNode{};

void initialize (BaseNode* node){/*..*/};
```

The use of `void*` in order to achieve generic code in C++ usually comes when dealing with C API's, like POSIX or Win32, and in your code you should avoid them.